# How Would I go About Subsetting this Data Frame?

Tags: r

I have the follow data frame:

```
> resident
     X LOS Age Meds MHealth DietRest ReligAff NmChores Employed EdLevel Courses
1   R1  27  35    2       1        3        2        2        0       2       1
2   R2  56  43    0       0        0        1        3        1       3       2
3   R3 101  41    1       1        0        0        2        2       2       3
4   R4  19  54    3       2        4        3        1        0       1       0
5   R5  34  29    0       0        0        2        3        0       2       1
6   R6  78  46    2       0        2        1        2        1       3       2
7   R7 134  51    3       2        4        0        1        1       3       2
8   R8 112  38    0       1        1        4        2        1       2       3
9   R9  83  61    3       1        3        2        2        0       4       3
10 R10   9  50    2       0        2        1        1        2       2       0
11 R11  67  23    0       1        0        0        2        0       3       1
12 R12  30  47    2       2        0        3        2        0       4       0
13 R13  95  65    4       1        4        2        2        0       3       2
14 R14 165  63    5       2        4        1        1        0       2       2
15 R15  29  40    0       1        0        0        3        2       5       0
16 R16  44  33    2       2        1        0        2        0       3       1
17 R17  36  48    2       1        0        3        2        0       1       1
18 R18  58  57    3       0        2        1        1        1       2       1
19 R19 116  39    0       1        0        2        2        1       3       1
20 R20  73  44    1       0        0        2        1        0       4       2
21 R21  79  30    3       2        3        3        1        0       2       1
22 R22  39  41    0       0        0        0        3        2       2       2
23 R23  18  50    2       1        2        1        1        1       3       0
24 R24  60  35    1       0        0        0        2        1       4       2
25 R25 106  48    3       2        3        2        2        0       2       2
26 R26  46  31    2       1        0        0        1        1       3       1
27 R27  52  59    2       0        1        1        3        2       2       1
28 R28  28  62    6       0        4        2        1        0       5       1
29 R29  79  45    4       2        3        3        2        1       3       2
30 R30  24  42    1       1        1        0        1        0       2       1
31 R31 123  36    3       1        0        2        2        1       3       4
32 R32  11  49    2       0        2        1        2        0       1       0
33 R33  95  26    1       1        0        1        3        0       3       4
34 R34  61  24    0       0        0        2        2        1       2       1
35 R35  88  63    2       1        0        1        1        1       4       2
36 R36  64  38    1       2        1        4        1        1       2       3
37 R37  99  40    2       0        0        1        3        2       4       1
>
```

LOS = length of stay

I am trying to go through the data frame and create a new column that consists of either a zero or one, based upon if the resident is completing an average of one course every thirty days. How would I go upon doing this? I understand I would need to do something like within this subset of people, break things down so that if someone has been there between thirty and fifty-nine days and has completed at least one course, they receive a value of one. If someone has been there between sixty and eighty-nine days and that person has finished at least two courses, give them a one, and so forth and if not give them a value of zero. How would I create a function that does this and adds a value of either 1 or 0 to a new vector based upon the data for each resident?

Comment: Maybe `as.numeric((resident$LOS - 30) / resident$Courses <= 30)`?

Comment: What constitutes "the resident"? I'm inferring `Age` is the age of each resident, suggesting you have 37 residents. What is a course? What is the measure of time here?

Comment: I think you need `pmax(1, resident$LOS - 30) / resident$Courses <= 30 `

Comment: @r2evans LOS stands for the length of their stay, and a resident is determined by R1, R2, R3, etc. For example, Resident 1 has stayed for 27 days and has taken 1 course

Comment: Any reason why this doesnt work? `subset(resident, 29<LOS<59 & Courses <=1)`

Comment: @AllanCameron @Ritchie Sacramento `subset(resident, 29<LOS<59 & Courses <=1) ` why doesnt this code work?

Comment: @Andrew, perhaps because `29 < LOS < 59` is not valid R syntax, you'll need to break that up into individual binary comparisons.

Comment: @r2evans is there not a better way to do it that I can compare LOS to both?

Comment: `29 < LOS & LOS < 59`